# Is it possible to compare the values of database table records using java?

Tags: java, database

I am new to programming and I am trying to write a java program which can solve the following problem:

> There are 100 students and 100 books.  The books are grouped under
> four category (Artificial intelligence, machine learning, deep
> learning and IOT ) and each category has 25 books. we can't give a
> book each student needs so that students will choose the books using
> category. then the program assigns one book from the category for each
> student by considering choose order and gpa of students' result. students will be compared by GPA so that the system
> will assign 1st choose, 2nd choose,....,4th choose based on
> comparison. one student will have only one book. I tried as following.

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
String query_s = "SELECT choice1,choice2, choice3, choice4, GPA FROM 
Students_table ";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query_s);
while (rs.next()) {
  double gpa = rs.getDouble("GPA");
  String choice1 = rs.getString("choice1");
  String choice2 = rs.getString("choice2");
  String choice3 = rs.getString("choice3");
  String choice4 = rs.getString("choice4");
  if (gpa > 3.5) {
    ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Students_table SET Book =" + choice1 + " ");
    ps.execute();
  }
  if (gpa < 3.5 && gpa > 3) {
    ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Students_table SET Book  =" + choice2 + "");
    ps.execute();
  }
  if (gpa < 3 && gpa > 2.5) {
    ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Students_table SET Book =" + choice3 + "");
    ps.execute();
  } else {
    ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Students_table SET Book  =" + choice4 + "");
    ps.execute();
  }
}
```

It says:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'MACHINE_LEARING' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'MACHINE_LEARING' is not a column in the target table. table "Students_table" looks at this.
[Students_table sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzHr5.png)

But I can't write a method to compare students using choose order and GPA to give the book they want. please help!

Comment: Please note the following which appears on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): ___DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc___ - _copy or type the text into the question_ So please [edit] your question and add the "Students_table" data as text.

Answer (score 0):

Use where to identify row and use `?` to avoid SQL Injection.

```
PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement("update Students_table set Book=? where Name=?");  
stmt.setString(1,"choice1"); 
stmt.setString(2,"Mark");
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, it's a comment. I wish to clarify your question.
Here is your sample data.

```
Name  Choice1                  Choice2                  Choice3  Choice4           GPA
====  =======================  =======================  =======  ================  ===
Mark  Machine_learning         Artificial_intelligence  IoT      Deep_learning     3.0
John  Artificial_intelligence  Machine_learning         IoT      Deep_learning     2.8
Ward  Deep_learning            Artificial_intelligence  IoT      Machine_learning  4.0
Mose  Machine_learning         Artificial_intelligence  IoT      Deep_learning     3.5
```

The expected result is as follows.

1. Ward is the student with the highest GPA so he is assigned his first choice which is *Deep_learning*.
2. Mose is the student with the second highest GPA so he also gets his first choice, which is *Machine_learning*, also because that book has not yet been assigned.
3. The student with the third highest GPA is Mark. His first choice – *Machine_learning* – has already been assigned (to Mose), so he gets his second choice – *Artificial_intelligence*.
4. That leaves John whose first and second choices have already been assigned, so he gets his third choice which is *IoT*

That means you need to perform the following UPDATE statements.

```sql
UPDATE Students_table SET Book = 'Deep_learning' WHERE Name = 'Ward'
UPDATE Students_table SET Book = 'Machine_learning' WHERE Name = 'Mose'
UPDATE Students_table SET Book = 'Artificial_intelligence' WHERE Name = 'Mark'
UPDATE Students_table SET Book = 'IoT' WHERE Name = 'John'
```

If the above is correct, then edit your question and add the above explanation and I will delete this "answer".